# Is the post I'm currently reviewing mine to review

Tags: discussion, review

So many questions are asked about reviews so this might have an answer somewhere.

[Servy's answer on this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181232/174490) got me wondering.

> This is simply a race condition. You're not the only person in the queue. Someone else reviewed an item while you were reviewing the first one. This will happen a lot in those queues.

So I get that once I get a post to review an enter the review mode, this post is mine to review and doesn't show up in another user's queue right ? (Unless it requires more than one approval but still one of these approval is locked to my account right now).

So unless I click Approve, Decline, Improve or Skip, this post is *mine to review*.
If all of this is true, what happens to the post if I

- Refresh my page a few times. (Does the post go back in the queue ?)
- Close my browser's current tab and then reopen it a few minutes later with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. (Is it still my post to review or has it gone back into queue)?

Comment: I dont believe they are locked to you because I am pretty sure I have clicked an option such as improve and received the notice that the review had already been completed by someone else. I would love to see a concrete answer to this.

Comment: once upon a time I proposed _[exclusive review period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155619/165773 "here")_. "By this, I mean that picked suggested edit is taken off the queue for 2-3 minutes so that no one else can review it until timeout expires. This would guarantee that my decisions (at least quick ones) could only clash with those of the user(s) who held the suggested edit longer than mentioned _timeout_..."

Comment: instread of just quick i think "Click here to give yourself 1 more minute to figure this out" They do that in some bank websites. Sometimes you need to research a question to see if its a dup etc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No.

This has happened to me a few times: I was reviewing a suggested edit, and I was typing a custom "reject" message. However, by the time I finish typing, I sometimes get a "This edit was already approved!" message.

[image]]

If you navigate away from the page and come back (or refresh) and the post has already been reviewed, you will get a message telling you that the post is not reviewable.

*(click image to enlarge)*
[image]

If it hasn't already been reviewed by the time you get back to it, you will still be able to review it.

Comment: Ah yes this was exactly the situation I commented about on the question. I believe you are correct.

Comment: Well well... Another case of Fastest gun in the west i presume.. but it's okay since someone could let is computer open and prevent some post to get a review.

Comment: I don't think first posts works like this though..

Comment: You should consider updating this, as everything in /review locks now.